# Specific explanation on operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

There's just 1 aspect that either I just can't see, or my brain is too wracked to understand, or I'm overthinking it like I usually do...

```
class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {};  //*****This line*****
    CVector (int a,int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    CVector operator + (const CVector&);
};
```

I cannot for the life of me understand what `"CVector () {};"` is doing in this operator overload/class. I understand `"CVector (int a,int b) : x(a), y(b) {}"` creates an object that is expecting 2 ints, and to assign those ints to `x` and `y`. I also understand that `"CVector operator + (const CVector&);"` is a prototype for the function involved in the overload.

But what is the line in question doing? Is it simply making a blank object with a blank default?

Comment: It is the default constructor. It is used when you default construct a `CVector`. It is orthogonal to operator overloading.

Comment: Titles and questions should agree.

Comment: @juanchopanza: why don't you write it up as an answer?

Comment: @ChristianSeverin Because this is way too trivial, is covered in any introductory book, and has been asked many times before. There would be no value in answering this (that's my opinion of course, others should feel free to answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVector () {}; is the default contructor, used to create an object from the CVector class (without passing any parameters like in the other constructor). It has nothing to do with operator overloading.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was confused because default constructors tutorial on the "cplusplus.com" website didn't have the curly braces. I was thinking the curly braces modified the default constructor further. Apparently not.